# How to convert one type to another in C++17 using template meta programming?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I need to implement a type converter in C++ to convert some type to another. For example, converting `int16_t` to `float` and `int64_t` to `double`. I have implemented one using template specialization:

```
template<class T>
struct TypeConverter
{

};
template<>
struct TypeConverter<int16_t>
{
       using type = float;
};

template<>
struct TypeConverter<int64_t>
{
       using type = double;
};

TEST(Exp, TypeConveter) {

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<TypeConverter<int16_t>::type, float>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<TypeConverter<int64_t>::type, double>);
}
```

Is there a better (more compact) way of achieving this using C++17 tmp features?

Comment: You need to tell us how you want to achieve. As it is we just have a struct with an alias defined. Do you have a method that actually converts? How is its signature? Do you need some data members or can it be a free function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CE C++17 : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/iY8Qoa

CE C++11 : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ApuxZj

**User Code**

```
#include<TypeMap.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using TMap = TypeMap <
    std::pair<int16_t, float>,
    std::pair<int64_t, double>
>;

void foo() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<TMap::get<int16_t>, float>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<TMap::get<int64_t>, double>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<TMap::get<int>, NotFound>);
}
```

**TypeMap.h**

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

struct NotFound;

template<class... TPs>
struct TypeMap {
    template<class T>
    using get = NotFound;
};

template<class TP1, class... TPs>
struct TypeMap<TP1, TPs...> {
    template<class T>
    using get = std::conditional_t< std::is_same_v<T, typename TP1::first_type>
            , typename TP1::second_type
            , typename TypeMap<TPs...>::template get<T> >;
};
```

Comment: "move code to library" ... I don't think that is the point of the question. Regardless of where you put the code, the question is if it can be written more compact. That's how I see the question at least.

Comment: @bolov After multiple iterations, I guess it is now compact enough.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way (compatible with C++11):

```
template<class T> struct Type {};

float type_convert(Type<int16_t>);
double type_convert(Type<int64_t>);

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(type_convert(Type<int16_t>{})), float>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(type_convert(Type<int64_t>{})), double>);
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that it uses argument-dependent name lookup (ADL) to find the corresponding `type_convert` function *declaration* (no *definition* necessary). If you need to handle user-defined types (UDT) it is easy to add corresponding overloads of `type_convert` for them in the same namespace where they are declared (without having to open the traits namespace to define another specialization of the trait class template for your UDT). E.g.:

```
namespace N { 
    struct MyType;
    long double type_convert(Type<MyType>);
}
```

And then:

```
// type_convert is found by ADL.    
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(type_convert(Type<N::MyType>{})), long double>);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most synthetic way I can imagine to register the types for a type converter is a couple of lists of types in a `std::tuple` (or something similar).

By example: if you want to convert `std::int16_t` to `float`, `std::int32_t` to `double` and `std::int64_t` to `long double`, you can `using` define the couple of types

```
using list1 = std::tuple<std::int16_t, std::int32_t, std::int64_t>;
using list2 = std::tuple<float, double, long double>;
```

Now, given the following struct and declared function

```
template <typename, typename, typename>
struct foo
 { using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct foo<T1, T1, T2>
 { using type = std::tuple<T2>; };

template <typename T, typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
constexpr auto bar (std::tuple<Ts1...>, std::tuple<Ts2...>)
   -> decltype( std::tuple_cat(
         std::declval<typename foo<T, Ts1, Ts2>::type>()...) );
```

the `TypeConverter` become

```
template <typename T>
using TypeConverter
   = std::tuple_element_t<0u, decltype(bar<T>(std::declval<list1>(),
                                              std::declval<list2>()))>;
```

But I suppose that a couple of list in two different `std::tuple`s is synthetic but difficult to understand and maintain.

So I propose a less synthetic (but more comprehensible and maintainable) way based on a single list of pair of types

```
using list = std::tuple<std::pair<std::int16_t, float>,
                        std::pair<std::int32_t, double>,
                        std::pair<std::int64_t, long double>>;
```

Now `struct` and declare function become

```
template <typename, typename>
struct foo
 { using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct foo<T1, std::pair<T1, T2>>
 { using type = std::tuple<T2>; };

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto bar (std::tuple<Ts...>)
   -> decltype( std::tuple_cat(
         std::declval<typename foo<T, Ts>::type>()...) );
```

and the `TypeConverter`

```
template <typename T>
using TypeConverter
   = std::tuple_element_t<0u, decltype(bar<T>(std::declval<list>()))>;
```

The following is a full compiling C++17 example with both solutions (you can enable the first or the second changing the `#if 0`)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

#if 0
template <typename, typename, typename>
struct foo
 { using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct foo<T1, T1, T2>
 { using type = std::tuple<T2>; };

template <typename T, typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
constexpr auto bar (std::tuple<Ts1...>, std::tuple<Ts2...>)
   -> decltype( std::tuple_cat(
         std::declval<typename foo<T, Ts1, Ts2>::type>()...) );

using list1 = std::tuple<std::int16_t, std::int32_t, std::int64_t>;
using list2 = std::tuple<float, double, long double>;

template <typename T>
using TypeConverter
   = std::tuple_element_t<0u, decltype(bar<T>(std::declval<list1>(),
                                              std::declval<list2>()))>;
#else

template <typename, typename>
struct foo
 { using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct foo<T1, std::pair<T1, T2>>
 { using type = std::tuple<T2>; };

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto bar (std::tuple<Ts...>)
   -> decltype( std::tuple_cat(
         std::declval<typename foo<T, Ts>::type>()...) );

using list = std::tuple<std::pair<std::int16_t, float>,
                        std::pair<std::int32_t, double>,
                        std::pair<std::int64_t, long double>>;

template <typename T>
using TypeConverter
   = std::tuple_element_t<0u, decltype(bar<T>(std::declval<list>()))>;
#endif

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<float, TypeConverter<std::int16_t>> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<double, TypeConverter<std::int32_t>> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<long double, TypeConverter<std::int64_t>> );
 }
```